# Gradle Сборка Jar проекта

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar

Необходимо из библиотеки сделать JAR файл. 
В документации прописано: выполните команду

`./gradlew jarRelease`

Вопрос куда ее вводить?) Пользуюсь Android-studio

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите через командную строку в корень проекта (там у вас должен лежать файл `gradlew.bat`), и введите там эту команду (`gradlew jarRelease`), например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В результате вы должны увидеть в командной строке следующий вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Android Studio в данном случае не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать через GUI студии - справа вверху вкладка `gradle`- `build`